# How to replace a string/pattern in nth column/field in a comma-separated .csv file using sed/awk?

Tags: csv, sed, awk

I have a .csv file ,i need to replace a string in 5th column by another string ,columns are seperated by ',' and each element in columns are bounded by " as shown below.

```
"ID","CIRCLE","IP_ADDRESS","DESCRIPTION","Current_Status"
"6","local","127.0.0.1","localhost","3"
"7","RPOP1","10.10.10.1","router1","3"
```

I need to replace all elements which are '3' in 5th column by string 'Alive'.

I have tried below script which is posted earlier in stackflow ,but it is not working for my case

```
/usr/bin/awk -F, '$5 ~ /3/ { OFS= ","; $5 = "Alive"; }' /tmp/HOST_REPORT.csv
```

Please provide a simple solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> but it is not working for my case

Because you didn't choose to print it.  Try:

```
/usr/bin/awk -F, '$5 ~ /3/ { OFS= ","; $5 = "Alive"; }1' /tmp/HOST_REPORT.csv
                                                      ^
```

In order to preserve the quotes, you could say:

```
/usr/bin/awk -F, '$5 ~ /3/ { OFS="," ; $5 = "\"Alive\""; }1' /tmp/HOST_REPORT.csv
```

Comment: Just be aware that if you're on Solaris then `/usr/bin/awk` is old, broken awk which should never be used. Use gawk, nawk, or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk. Hopefully it's OK with the OP that in the posted script `$5 ~ /3/` will match `"95437"` (for example), not just `"3"` and IMHO if your FS and OFS have the same value you should set them together for clarity. I'd write it as`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $5 == "\"3\"" {$5 = "\"Alive\""}1'`.

Comment: Further I need to replace '2' with 'recovering' and '1' with 'down' in same 5th column ,please provide the solution in single line.Thank you.

Comment: @user2914966 You can say `awk -F, '{ OFS="," ; if ($5 ~ /1/) {$5="\"down\""}; if ($5 ~ /2/) {$5="\"recovering\""}; if ($5 ~ /3/) {$5="\"Alive\""}; }1' inputfile`